# Wcf binding type from wsdl

Tags: wcf, wsdl

Is there a way to retrieve wcf binding type and security mode just from a wsdl?
i.e. I want to know what bindings are supported by a wcf service by reading it's wsdl, is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - the WSDL only defines what operations are available on your service - plus it is totally unaware of and independent of WCF.

The only thing that might be included in WSDL (depending on where it came from) are certain bits of information about security needed, e.g. whether to connect using http vs. https, or other tidbits.

Marc